# Many to many relationship: how to relate different entities with the same one

Tags: mysql, sql

There are services that can be subscribed by both companies or people:

```
        <--> copany subscription rel <--> company
Service 
        <--> person subscription rel <--> person
```

Consider I also have bunches of tables to link to the subscription tables (conditions, surveys etc). But I can't link these tables having two subscription tables.

So I thought to use this solution:

```
                          <--> company
Service <--> suvscription 
                          <--> person
```

The problem now is that I have two ids in subscription (id_person and id_company), linked to the two tables (one of which is null). So still it doesn't look to me a good solution.

What do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think that two relations is the better way to do it.

Comment: yes, but in that case how do I link survey for example? That should be a survery for one subscription. Should it have id_subscription_person or id_subscription_company?

Answer (score 0):

Why not separately store each entity's relationship to the service in a different table, like so:

COMPANY_SUBSCRIPTION

company_id|service_id

PERSON_SUBSCRIPTION

person_id|service_id

For these two tables above, both columns become your primary key, and several companies or people can be tied to the same service.

COMPANY

company_id|company_name..

PERSON

person_id|person_name...

SERVICE

service_id|service_name..